# Custom View with canvas in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom view in which you can draw with your fingers, I fill out a recyclerview with this view, made an adapter, and for example a list with size = 10 is obtained, where each item is a custom view, and if the user draws for example in item with position 5 then when scrolling the same picture appears in another item where he did not draw.
here is my adapter:

```
class CustomViewListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private var listSchedule = ArrayList<Int>()

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var calendarView: CustomView= itemView.calendar!!
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.schedule_item,
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = listSchedule.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
     holder.calendarView.setValue(listSchedule[position] )
}

fun setSchedules(listSchedule: ArrayList<Int>) {
    this.listSchedule = listSchedule
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

}

Comment: I was wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with this post so that I can edit and improve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of how RecyclerView works? Lets assume you have 1000 items in your list. A simple approach would be to create 1000 views from your `schedule_item` layout bind them and show them in e.g. a scrollview. However, doing that would cost a lot of time and memory. So the clever Android developers came up with the following idea: 
Since of the 1000 items only e.g. 10 are visible at the same time, lets just create 10 views and only change the content of the views depending on the actual item they show. So the 10 views are reused or recycled.
For this to work, the `onBindViewHolder` implementation must make sure that it updates the provided viewholder in a way that it shows the content of the item at the given position.

Now in your code, all you do in `onBindViewHolder` is, to set a single integer. There is no sign of setting any custom drawing etc. So I assume the drawing is just stored inside the CustomView. And since there are only those 10 or so CustomViews (as explained above), when they are reused to show a different item, they contain the original drawings because you didn't change that in `onBindViewHolder`.